# Spark create a temp directory structure on each node

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on a spark java wrapper which uses third party libraries, which will read files from a hard coded directory name say "resdata" from where job executes. I know this is twisted but will try to explain. 
when I execute the job it is trying to find the required files in the path something like this below,
/data/Hadoop/yarn/local//appcache/application_xxxxx_xxx/container_00_xxxxx_xxx/resdata 
I am assuming it is looking for the files in the current data directory , under that looking for directory name "resdata". At this point I don't know how to configure the current directory to any path on hdfs or local. 
So looking for options to create directory structure similar to what the third party libraries expecting and copying required files over there. This I need to do on each node. I am working on spark 2.2.0
Please help me in achieving this?

Comment: Are you 100% positive that your library wants to read data from the data node? What is HADOOP_CONF_DIR  set to? What is the exact filepath specified including the "file:///" or "hdfs:///" part. If local datanode access is required, use the spart-submit --files option to copy files to each node.

Answer (score 0):

just now got the answer I need to put all the files under resdata directory and zip it say restdata.zip, pass the file using the options "--archives" . Then each node will have directory restdata.zip/restdata/file1 etc